# Cannot find module 'require-dir' error while running gulp app:serve rails

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp

I installed npm, bower and gulp. But while running gulp app:serve, I am getting the following error. 
Please help me.
This is the command I run:
*sachin@sachin:~/Desktop/workspace/myproj/angular/ex (master)$gulp app:serve*

Result I got:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'require-dir'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sachin/Desktop/workspace/myproj/angular/ex/gulpfile.js:14:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Comment: Did you also run `npm install` from the `ex` directory?

Comment: did you install `require-dir -g` (global?)

Comment: @robertklep - I didn't install it before and now, after running npm install, getting error as **Error: Cannot find module 'wiredep'**

Comment: @LucasRodriguez - i haven't install

Comment: @robertklep - `npm install` did the trick, I missed it.

Comment: `npm install  require-dir` must be executed

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Error: Cannot find module 'require-dir'

You've installed gulp but have not installed its tasks' dependencies. E.g. if a gulp task has any `require('')` calls, then it depends on [require-dir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir). Those dependencies are probably in your project's package.json file. To install all the dependencies run:

```
npm install
```